# Postfix in Localhost

Tags: postfix, localhost

I have set postfix in localhost. but why it reject to use the other username except my computer name. i've set the main.cf as follow:

```
myhostname = yuki
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = yuki.com yuki localhost.localdomain localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

when i type from terminal:

```
sudo telnet localhost 25 ==>the result is ok, as follow:
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 yuki ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
```

but when i type from terminal:

```
sudo telnet yuki.com 25==>the result is:
telnet: could not resolve yuki.com/25: Name or service not known
```

but when i type from terminal:

```
sudo telnet yuki-PC 25==> the result is:
Trying 127.0.1.1...
Connected to yuki-PC.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 yuki ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
```

Note:yuki-PC is my computer name.

and also when I send email, the email is sent, but when i look in `/home/yuki/Maildir/new` there is no email there.

help me please, i'm really newbie in network.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `yuki.com` domain to the `/etc/hosts` and try again:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost yuki-PC yuki.com
```

Answer (score 0):

regarding the emails not being delivered, make sure you have a delivery agent configured correctly, SMTP only receives and transfers email, doesn't actually deliver it to the end user. your case might be either of the below,

1) **local_transport** is ill configured .

2) for the local users the emails might have been delivered to **/var/spool/mail/$username**

- login as the recipient user on the server and issue **/bin/mail** to see if any emails are listed